# Como criar uma coluna que marque X se uma das condições de duas variaveis for verdadeira:

Tags: r, data.rable-r

Estou tentando criar uma coluna que cria a coluna alunos, e marque um 1 ou um True, se freq < 75 ou
critico > 4.

Até o momento conseguir ir até esse ponto no R:

```
library(data.table)

critico <- critico[, alunos := valor( freq < 75||critico > 4),  by= .(id_escola, id_etapa, encrypted)]
```

Comment: Tente com só uma barra `|` em vez de `||`. A primeira é a disjunção vetorizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### | versus ||

Como apontado por @rui-barradas nos comentários, use `|` ao invés de `||`. `|` e `&` fazem avaliação elemento a elemento, retornando um vetor com mesmo comprimento do vetor da esquerda (p.e., no caso de `x | y`, do comprimento de *x*). `||` e `&&` faz a comparação apenas entre os primeiros elementos, retornando um vetor de comprimento 1. Veja a diferença:

```
a <- c(NA, 1:3)
b <- c(NA, 3:1)

a > 2 | b < 2
#> [1]    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE

a > 2 || b < 2
#> [1] NA
```

Consulte `?Logic` para detalhes.

### sintaxe do *data.table*

Dois pontos quanto a seu código: 1) `:=` opera por referência, não precisa usar atribuição; 2) se a comparação só depende dos valores de cada linha, não precisa indicar grupo. Por exemplo:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(grupo = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 3), a = 1:3, b = 3:1)

dt[, c := a > 2 | b < 2]

dt
#>    grupo a b     c
#> 1:     A 1 3 FALSE
#> 2:     A 2 2 FALSE
#> 3:     A 3 1  TRUE
#> 4:     B 1 3 FALSE
#> 5:     B 2 2 FALSE
#> 6:     B 3 1  TRUE
```

Se quer algum código específico, pode usar `fifelse`. Por exemplo:

```
dt[, c := fifelse(a > 2 | b < 2, "X", "")]

dt
#>    grupo a b c
#> 1:     A 1 3
#> 2:     A 2 2
#> 3:     A 3 1 X
#> 4:     B 1 3
#> 5:     B 2 2
#> 6:     B 3 1 X
```